# How to find quality parameter in compressjs dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, math, compression

My file size is 500kb (It will come dynamically anysize). And my target is 150kb.

For some reasons i can choose only quality

```
new Compressor(selectedFile1, {
            quality: targetRatio,
```

i.e., If i pass targetRatio to 0.7, it will reduce image to 159kb~

To find the targetRatio dynamically what i did is

```
var targetRatio = fileSize / 150;
```

But, I cannot figure out how to do find the targetRatio to get exact value i.e., to reduce into 150kb

[Here's the place to test](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/compressorjs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reaching 150kb modifying the quality, won't work for every image.

> The amount of JPEG compression is typically measured as a percentage of the quality level. An image at 100% quality has (almost) no loss, and 1% quality is a very low quality image. In general, quality levels of 90% or higher are considered "high quality", 80%-90% is "medium quality", and 70%-80% is low quality.

If you would use a 15.594 x 3.936 jpg ([example](https://i.redd.it/xa0hjygge3831.jpg)) which may be at ~2.5mb depending on the information stored, you wouldn't be able to reach 150kb in jpg format.

So targeting 150kb would be `150.000 / 2.500.000 = 0.06`.

[image]

As you can see from the result size of the screenshot, this is not possible, you have to do multiple converts and test if the result size is exactly or below 150kb by reducing width & height. But compressing the original image from my example using the quality of 0.06 will result in an image around 800KB.

```js
fetch('https://i.imgur.com/mw7BsYS.jpg')
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(async blob => {
    let {
      size
    } = blob;

    console.log("Startingsize", size, 'B');
    let img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    await new Promise((r) => img.onload = r);
    let {
      naturalWidth,
      naturalHeight
    } = img;
    
    console.log(naturalWidth, naturalHeight, size);
    const targetByte = 150 * 1024;
    // in case first picture is smaller than 150kb
    let compressed = { result: blob };
    // speeds up large pictures
    if (targetByte / size < 0.15) {
      naturalWidth *= 0.15;
      naturalHeight *= 0.15;
    } else if (targetByte / size < 0.25) {
      naturalWidth *= 0.25;
      naturalHeight *= 0.25;
    } else if (targetByte / size < 0.5) {
      naturalWidth *= 0.5;
      naturalHeight *= 0.5;
    } else if (targetByte / size < 0.75) {
      naturalWidth *= 0.75;
      naturalHeight *= 0.75;
    }

    // generate thumbnails
    while (size > targetByte) {
      if (blob.size > targetByte) {
        // the bigger the steps, the faster it will be.
        naturalWidth *= 0.99;
        naturalHeight *= 0.99;
      }
      let res = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const res = new Compressor(blob, {
          maxWidth: naturalWidth,
          maxHeight: naturalHeight,
          success(blob) {
            size = blob.size;
            console.log(naturalWidth, naturalHeight, size);
            compressed = res;
            resolve();
          },
          error: reject
        })
      });
    }

    // replace the compressed with the original image from above
    const original = img.src;
    img.onclick = () => { if (confirm("sure?")) img.src = original; };

    // compressed.result contains the final blob now
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(compressed.result);

    await new Promise((r) => img.onload = r);
    console.log(compressed.result, img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight)

    document.body.append(img);
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/compressorjs/1.1.1/compressor.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get this exactly to one size is almost impossible. There are too many factors.  You can roughly determine it by a rule of three or take the information from Christoph. I would reduce the image size in advance and you should always consider the quality.  You could otherwise use .gif, but this supports only 256 colors, but would be smaller.